# why postman api body is not responding?

Tags: postman

[image]I'm trying to make a post request through postman. I selected the post option and when I'm trying to add something to the body, I could not do it as the entire body is not editable. Has anyone faced this kind of issue before? The body is part is not responding at all.[image]

Comment: Can you add a picture or other reference to your question to better help you?

Comment: @GrayCygnus Added!

Comment: Well, to me it looks clickable (you even have your cursor in the body). Is this the part that becomes unclickable? Please show us that part

Comment: It looks like that is the body of the response, not a body parameter.  What happens if you scroll up?

Comment: @GrayCygnus I added the details I could.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to edit the body of the response.  To modify the body parameter, scroll up and select the "Body" tab. 
[image: body tab]

If you would like to insert raw JSON, switch to the `raw` selection under the Body tab

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot after scrolling up?  Is there an Authorization tab where you are trying to edit?

Comment: @SarathVelamuri please add more details and pics regarding your problem, so we can actually see what parts are not clickable

Comment: I added the screenshot after scrolling up.

Comment: I got it. It should be in raw mode under the Body to take users input.